# Cucumber steps - testing an EJB service with a persistence context

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, testing, cucumber

I have a stateless EJB that uses `@PersistenceContext` with a `EntityManager`, I'm writing a cucumber step definitions class that uses this Service to perform steps in testing finding users based upon supplied criteria.

So for example

```
@Stateless
public class UserService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void add(String userName) {
        User user = new User(userName);
        em.persist(user);
    }    

    public List<User> findByName(String userName) {
        return em.createQuery("Select u from User as u WHERE u.name LIKE :userName").setParameter("userName", userName).getResultList();
    }

}
```

And a feature file that looks something like

```
Feature: Search

    Given a user with the name 'Jason Statham'
        And another user with the name 'Bill Gates'
        And another user with the name 'Larry Page'
    When the customer searches for a user with the name 'Jason'
    Then 1 users should have been found
        And User 1 should have a name of 'Jason Statham'
```

And a steps definition class

```
 public class SearchStepsDefinitions {

   private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
   private UserService userService = new UserService();

   @Given(value = ".+user with the name '(.+)'$")
   public void a_user_with_the_name(final String userName) {
       userService.add(userName);
   }

   @When(value = "^the customer searches for a user with the name '(.+)'$")
   public void the_customer_searches_for_a_user_with_the_name(final String name) {
       userList = userService.findByName(name); 
   }

   @Then(value = "(\\d+) users should have been found$")
   public void users_should_have_been_found(final int userCount) {
       assertThat(userList.size(), equalTo(userCount));
   }

   @Then(value = "User (\\d+) should have a name of '(.+)'$")
   public void should_have_a_name_of(final int position, final String name) {
       assertThat(userList.get(position - 1).getName(), equalTo(name)); 
   }

}
```

Now I understand that as the Service is an EJB the `EntityManager` is injected
via the `@PersistenceContext`.

My question is in the steps definition how should I be dealing with this dependency? Should I be mocking it and injecting this mock into the `UserService`, or should the `UserService` have a setter for the `EntityManager` and use a `EntityManagerFactory` to create one in the `SearchStepsDefinitions`?

So in other words

```
@Stateless
public class UserService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void add(String userName) {
        User user = new User(userName);
        em.persist(user);
    }    

    public List<User> findByName(String userName) {
        return em.createQuery("Select u from User as u WHERE u.name LIKE :userName").setParameter("userName", userName).getResultList();
    }

    public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

}
```

Then the steps definition would either be this

```
public class SearchStepsDefinitions {

   private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

   @Mock
   private EntityManager em;       

   @Inject
   @InjectMocks
   private UserService userService;

   @Given(value = ".+user with the name '(.+)'$")
   public void a_user_with_the_name(final String userName) {
       userService.add(userName);
   }

   @When(value = "^the customer searches for a user with the name '(.+)'$")
   public void the_customer_searches_for_a_user_with_the_name(final String name) {
       userList = userService.findByName(name); 
   }

   @Then(value = "(\\d+) users should have been found$")
   public void users_should_have_been_found(final int userCount) {
       assertThat(userList.size(), equalTo(userCount));
   }

   @Then(value = "User (\\d+) should have a name of '(.+)'$")
   public void should_have_a_name_of(final int position, final String name) {
       assertThat(userList.get(position - 1).getName(), equalTo(name)); 
   }

}
```

Or this

```
public class SearchStepsDefinitions {

   private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

   private UserService userService = new UserService();

   @Before
   public void setup() {
       userService.setEm(Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("punit").createEntityManager());
   }

   @Given(value = ".+user with the name '(.+)'$")
   public void a_user_with_the_name(final String userName) {
       userService.add(userName);
   }

   @When(value = "^the customer searches for a user with the name '(.+)'$")
   public void the_customer_searches_for_a_user_with_the_name(final String name) {
       userList = userService.findByName(name); 
   }

   @Then(value = "(\\d+) users should have been found$")
   public void users_should_have_been_found(final int userCount) {
       assertThat(userList.size(), equalTo(userCount));
   }

   @Then(value = "User (\\d+) should have a name of '(.+)'$")
   public void should_have_a_name_of(final int position, final String name) {
       assertThat(userList.get(position - 1).getName(), equalTo(name)); 
   }

}
```

Essentially I'm trying to do the same as [this example](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/spring-txn/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/spring/txn/SeeMessagesStepdefs.java) but I'm not using Spring

Or perhaps another option would be to not have the service as an EJB and `@Inject` the EntityManager into it

```
public class UserService {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    public void add(String userName) {
        User user = new User(userName);
        em.persist(user);
    }    

    public List<User> findByName(String userName) {
        return em.createQuery("Select u from User as u WHERE u.name LIKE :userName").setParameter("userName", userName).getResultList();
    }

}
```

And then the steps would look like

```
 public class SearchStepsDefinitions {

   private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

   @Inject
   private UserService userService;

   @Given(value = ".+user with the name '(.+)'$")
   public void a_user_with_the_name(final String userName) {
       userService.add(userName);
   }

   @When(value = "^the customer searches for a user with the name '(.+)'$")
   public void the_customer_searches_for_a_user_with_the_name(final String name) {
       userList = userService.findByName(name); 
   }

   @Then(value = "(\\d+) users should have been found$")
   public void users_should_have_been_found(final int userCount) {
       assertThat(userList.size(), equalTo(userCount));
   }

   @Then(value = "User (\\d+) should have a name of '(.+)'$")
   public void should_have_a_name_of(final int position, final String name) {
       assertThat(userList.get(position - 1).getName(), equalTo(name)); 
   }

}
```

I'm not really sure of the pro's and con's of these approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much digging I discovered I need to use an EJBContainer, then the Steps class now looks like this

```
 public class SearchStepsDefinitions {

   private Context context;
   private EJBContainer container;

   private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

   private UserService userService;

   @cucumber.api.java.Before
   public void setup() {
       ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
       context = ejbContainer.getContext();

       userService = (UserService) context.lookup("java:global/classes/UserService");
   }

   @cucumber.api.java.After
   public void teardown() {
       ejbContainer.close();
   }

   @Given(value = ".+user with the name '(.+)'$")
   public void a_user_with_the_name(final String userName) {
       userService.add(userName);
   }

   @When(value = "^the customer searches for a user with the name '(.+)'$")
   public void the_customer_searches_for_a_user_with_the_name(final String name) {
       userList = userService.findByName(name); 
   }

   @Then(value = "(\\d+) users should have been found$")
   public void users_should_have_been_found(final int userCount) {
       assertThat(userList.size(), equalTo(userCount));
   }

   @Then(value = "User (\\d+) should have a name of '(.+)'$")
   public void should_have_a_name_of(final int position, final String name) {
       assertThat(userList.get(position - 1).getName(), equalTo(name)); 
   }

}
```

One additional thing that is required is a ejb container in the pom. I used glassfish, with this dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
```